# Регулярка под формат даты

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Появилась необходимость написать регулярку для нахождения в строке дат такого формата `2020-12-06 21:00:00.0000000 +00:00` Накидал вот такую примитивную регулярку `/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{7} \+\d{2}:\d{2}/` но выглядит она не очень. Есть ли возможность как-то это дело сократить и написать более адекватно?

Comment: Более адекватно будет добавить диапазоны для дат, ведь не бывает 13 месяца и 50-го дня в году, не так ли?

Comment: Проверять валидность даты задачи не стоит, нужно проверять именно формат. Это написано в заголовке. Любые строки такого формата нужно обнаруживать в тексте не зависимо сколько там месяцев 12 или 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Сократить можно заменой `\d{2}` на `\d\d`, хотя, это скорее вопрос стилистики.

   ```
   /\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d{7} \+\d\d:\d\d/
   ```
2. Вообще регулярка совершенно адекватная и простая. Можно было бы удваивать группы, но особой пользы от этого не будет, скорее наоборот станет сложнее читать:

   ```
   /\d{4}(-\d\d){2} (\d\d:){2}\d\d\.\d{7} \+\d{2}:\d{2}/
   ```
3. Обращаю внимание, что ты не проверяешь на начало и конец строки, что означает, что любое вхождение такое подстроки сматчится.
4. Само собой, эта регулярка проверяет только на корректность формата, но не на корректность самой даты.

Comment: Спасибо. Просто не особо разбираюсь в регулярках, думал что не правильно написал. По задаче мне и нужно искать в тексте подобные строки дат и заменять их другим форматом.